# validation of a project file using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a file name something like this sca_HelloWorld_rev2.0.jar

```
sca_{ProjectName}_rev{revisionId}.jar 

Id can be 2.11 ,3.0,3,4.0,5,4.564

ProjectName can be HelloWorld,HelloWorld123,Hello_world
```

I am trying to do regex validation in java ?How can i achieve this in Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static boolean isValid(String s){
    return s.matches("^sca_\\w+?_rev\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\.jar$");
}
```

`\\w+` matches one or more word characters, i.e. `A-Z a-z 0-9 _`.

`\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?` matches one or more digits, optionally followed by a `.` and one or more digits.

The `^` and `$` represents the start and end of the string.

Comment: I'd add a '+' after your first digit, in case the major version can be greater than a single digit:
^sca_\\w+_rev\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\.jar$

Comment: @ggrigery. Thanks, I agree. It was omitted by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String function matches. So for your case

```
projectName.matches("sca_(HelloWorld|HelloWorld123|Hello_world)_rev(2.11|3.0|3|4.0|5|4.564).jar");
```

Check out http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to test your regular expression

Edit: assuming your project name could really be anything, and your revision number could be in the format of either #, #.## then use this regular expression

projectName.matches("sca_.+_rev[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*.jar") would return true for these inputs.

"sca_ADJOWE_rev2.12315.jar".matches("sca_.+_rev[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*.jar") = TRUE

"sca_PROJECT1_rev6.jar".matches("sca_.+_rev[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*.jar") = TRUE

"sca_HELLOWORLD_rev2.1.jar".matches("sca_.+_rev[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*.jar") = TRUE

"sca_HELLOWORLD_rev2.1.152.jar".matches("sca_.+_rev[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*.jar") = FALSE

"sca_rev2.1.jar".matches("sca_.+_rev[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*.jar") = FALSE

Go to the link I sent above, put in that regular expression and place in some test inputs and play with it if you need more fine tuning.

Comment: Project name can be anything i gave an example

Answer (score 0):

This pattern must be efficient:

```
sca_\w+?_rev\d.\d{1,3}\.jar
```